# error C2512 in precompiled header file?

Tags: c++, vector, structure, visual-studio-2013, precompiled-headers

I'm having a ridiculously strange problem.  When I try to run the program below, there's an error message that says: "error C2512: 'Record' : no appropriate default constructor available".  And when I double-click it, it directs me to a precompiled read-only header file named "xmemory0".  Do they expect me to change a read-only file?  Here's the segment of code in the file it directs me to:

```
void construct(_Ty *_Ptr)
{   // default construct object at _Ptr 
    ::new ((void *)_Ptr) _Ty();  // directs me to this line
}
```

Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int NG = 4; // number of scores

struct Record
{
    string name;  // student name
    int scores[NG];
    double average;

    // Calculate the average
    // when the scores are known
    Record(int s[], double a)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for(int count = 0; count != NG; count++)
        {
            scores[count] = s[count];
            sum += scores[count];
        }

        average = a;
        average = sum / NG;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Names of the class
    string names[] = {"Amy Adams", "Bob Barr", "Carla Carr",
                      "Dan Dobbs", "Elena Evans"};

    // exam scores according to each student
    int exams[][NG]= { {98, 87, 93, 88},
                       {78, 86, 82, 91},
                       {66, 71, 85, 94},
                       {72, 63, 77, 69},
                       {91, 83, 76, 60}};

    vector<Record> records(5);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* have a default constructor for Record, and `vector<Record> records(5)` requires one.  Visual Studio is notoriously unhelpful with its template error messages.  If you go to the Output tab as opposed to the Errors tab, you'll see a cascade of error messages, the first of which is the one you have found, and the last of which should point to your `vector` line.

If you click on the error message, then switch to the Output tab, scroll down through the lengthy error message until you reach a reference to your own code, then figure out the fix.

Here's the complete error message.  Line 44 in my source is your `vector` line:

```
D:\dev12\VC\INCLUDE\xmemory0(588) : error C2512: 'Record' : no appropriate default constructor available
        D:\dev12\VC\INCLUDE\xmemory0(587) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::c
nstruct(_Ty *)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=Record
        ]
        D:\dev12\VC\INCLUDE\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>:
construct(_Ty *)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=Record
        ]
        D:\dev12\VC\INCLUDE\type_traits(572) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' bein
 compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=Record
        ]
        D:\dev12\VC\INCLUDE\vector(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Alloc>' being c
mpiled
        with
        [
            _Alloc=std::allocator<Record>
        ]
        z.cpp(44) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<Record,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compi
ed
        with
        [
            _Ty=Record
        ]
```